# AWS EBS - Disable automatic snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

On AWS, I would like to disable automatic snapshots that are created for EBS volumes.
I have a training-purpose AWS account and would like to avoid the additional costs that snapshots bring. When I create an EC2 instance, its EBS is "snapshot" twice a day.

Where can I find this option? I know that I can achieve this with the lifecycle manager, but the EBS volumes need to have a tag.

Thank you!

Best regards, G

Comment: AWS doesn't created automatic snapshots of ebs volumes unless configured to do so. You can check aws backup and amazon eventbridge(find rules). Do you have a rule to make ami twice a day for you ec2 instances?

Comment: There's also the Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager service, which can automate EBS snapshot creation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html You would need to check there as well. As mentioned above, none of this is done by Amazon by default, you would have had to setup one of those automated backup services in order to be getting automated EBS snapshots.

Comment: Thanks, Riz and Mark.

Hm I do not remember that I set any policy to create two snapshots a day for EBS.
Also checked AWS Backup, Amazon event bridge and Lifecycle Manager, and not found anything there :(

EDIT: Checked Cloudtrail logs and found that third-party software connected to my account is creating those snapshots. Thank again!